# 'CKEditor' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Nn0.png)

'CKEditor' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its instance type 'CKEditor' is not a valid JSX element.
The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/mihail/webdev/work/OUTRUNSOLUTION/lab_monorepo/admin/node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
Type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
Property 'children' is missing in type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor>' but required in type 'ReactPortal'.ts(2786)